# JSDOC как правильно указать тип?

Tags: jsdoc

Всему сообществу ДВС!
Возникла следующая ситуация. Есть элементарная функция:

```
getDataType(data){
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(data).slice(8, -1);
};
```

При этом необходимо вести документацию с помощью JSDoc. Описание получается следующего вида:

```
/**
 * getDataType - description
 *
 * @param  {type} data description
 * @return {type}      description
 */
```

Вопрос - как правильно указать type в @param, ведь предполагается, что это может быть параметр абсолютно любого типа?
Заранее благодарен всем за ответы и за участие!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете указать любой тип данных вот так:

```
/**
 * Something
 * @param {*} anth - anything
 */
function(anth){};
```

Ссылка на документацию:  http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#multiple-types-and-repeatable-parameters